# Twenty Seventeen search error

Tags: themes, errors

Whenever I search something on my wordpress site, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_exID() in 
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php:360 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): 
twentyseventeen_excerpt_more(' [&hellip;]') #1 /var/www/html/wp-
includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters(' [&hellip;]', Array) 
#2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/formatting.php(3315): 
apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' [&hellip;]') #3 /var/www/html/wp-
includes/class-wp-hook.php(300): wp_trim_excerpt('<p>Today I will...') 
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook-
>apply_filters('', Array) #5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/post-
template.php(397): apply_filters('get_the_excerpt', '', 
Object(WP_Post)) #6 /var/www/html/wp-includes/post-template.php(362): 
get_the_excerpt() #7 /var/www/html/wp-
content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/post/content-
excerpt.php(43): the_excerpt() #8 /var/www/html/wp-
includes/template.php(690): require('/var/www/html/w...') #9 
/var/www/html/wp-includes/template.php(647): load_template('/var in 
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php on line 360
```

where the post summary is supposed to be. How can I fix it?

Comment: `get_exID()` is not part of the Twenty Seventeen theme. Perhaps the theme has been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NerdOfLinux from the error what I can see that you are using undefined function `get_exID()`... WordPress has a function [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/).

Change the function name `get_exID()` into `get_the_ID()`.

Answer (score 1):

The get_exID() function shouldn't exist in functions.php and doesn't exist in WordPress. I would recommend re-installing the theme. If you were making your own modifications to the theme be sure to do so via a child theme and don't manually edit the twenty seventeen theme.

If you didn't edit anything then make sure your site's security hasn't been compromised - you may want to consider changing your passwords to be safe.